# CSS - table progress bar with right arrow on table cells

Tags: css, progress-bar

I need to make a progress bar using `<table>`. I'd like the step elements to have an arrow on the right side. This is a .jpg of what I want:

[image: Progress bar with steps with right arrows]

This is the code I have so far:

```
<table class="progress-steps">
    <tr>
        <td class="step-done">Select tours</td>
        <td class="step-active">Enter info</td>
        <td class="step-unfinished">Confirm</td>
        <td class="step-unfinished">Pay</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
.progress-steps {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.progress-steps td {
    border-right: 4px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.progress-steps td:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}

.step-done {
    background-color: #305599;
    color: #849fd4;
}

.step-active {
    background-color: #5f81c1;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.step-unfinished {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #9fb6df;
}

.step-unfinished {
    border-right-color: #9fb6df !important;
}
</style>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called "Breadcrumb". There are plenty of examples online. Conceptually I'd suggest to use an unordered list rather than a table. It makes more sense to me. [This](https://catalin.red/css3-breadcrumbs/) could be a good starting point for your needs.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use tables is to use full width and let the elements take up as space as they need depending on text length. When using lists as in the link, they get all messed up on small devices when getting divided into multiple lines.

Comment: Ok. In this case I would suggest to still use an unordered list with some modern display flex to achieve what you want. CSS Triks has perhaps the best article ever made about flexboxes.